# JTabbedPane: How to order tabs from top to bottom, instead of bottom to top?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

In a `JTabbedPane`, the order of the tabs is from bottom to top:
[image]

I would like it to be top to bottom, meaning tab0 would be at the top row, and tab60 at the bottom row.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Class1 {

    public static JTabbedPane jtp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Parent frame");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(600, 400);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        window.add(jtp);

        /*WindowsTabbedPaneUI btpui = new WindowsTabbedPaneUI() {
            @Override protected void paintTabArea(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex) {
                int tabCount = tabPane.getTabCount();

                Rectangle iconRect = new Rectangle(),
                          textRect = new Rectangle();
                Rectangle clipRect = g.getClipBounds();

                // Paint tabRuns of tabs from front to back
                for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++) {
                    int start = tabRuns[i];
                    int next = tabRuns[(i == runCount - 1)? 0 : i + 1];
                    int end = (next != 0? next - 1: tabCount - 1);
                    for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
                        if (j != selectedIndex && rects[j].intersects(clipRect)) {
                            paintTab(g, tabPlacement, rects, j, iconRect, textRect);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Paint selected tab if its in the front run
                // since it may overlap other tabs
                if (selectedIndex >= 0 && rects[selectedIndex].intersects(clipRect)) {
                    paintTab(g, tabPlacement, rects, selectedIndex, iconRect, textRect);
                }
            }
        };
        jtp.setUI(btpui);*/

        //jtp.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
            jtp.addTab("tab"+i, new JPanel());
        }
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have tried overriding the `paintTabArea()` method in `WindowsTabbedPaneUI` to paint from top to bottom, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I have found 2 workarounds:

- Put the tabs at the bottom so that they are aligned in the correct way (but I'd like to keep them on top)
- Order the tabs in reverse order, then put the component in Right-To-Left alignment. However, this creates visual glitches: the tabs at the left are too close to the border, there is a space between the tabs at the left and the others, and the tabs at the right make a dent on the border. I would also have to override the `addTab()` method, and put in LTR when there is only one line, which feels like a hack.
  [image]

Is there any way to do this without glitches? I guess I have to override some method from `BasicTabbedPaneUI`, but I can't find which one.

Comment: And them in reverse order?

Comment: If I do that, then I need to put them in RTL alignment, and it causes glitches.

Comment: Does it cause glitches when it's done in forward order? I mean doing something like `for (int i = 60; I >= 0; I--) {` to simply reverse the order in which the tabs themselves are added

Comment: No, but the tabs are then from right to left, instead of left to right (hence the need to use RTL): http://puu.sh/AdFlo.png

Comment: I can't particularly see why changing to RTL would cause issues.  Unfortunately, I'm running on MacOS so I can't test it :P

Comment: Me neither, though RTL is more like a hack. Ideally I'd override some method in `WindowsTabbedPaneUI`, but I can't find which one.

Comment: Create your own UI using buttons to represent the tabs and then a CardLayout for each of the panels. When you click the button you would display the appropriate panel in the CardLayout.

Comment: 60 tabs seems like a ridiculous quantity.  Can’t they be grouped in any fashion?  A tabbed window with 6 tabs, each containing a tabbed window with 10 tabs?  Or vis-versa?  Depending on the Look&Feel, the active tab will always be moved to the row closest to the client area, so the tab with row 0 may not stay on the top.

Comment: When I add them in reverse order with RTL, I do not experience glitches.  See:  https://imgur.com/a/jrdfeFb

Comment: Also the reason your paint override method doesn't change anything is that the coordinates of the tab rectangles are precalculated.  You would have to override `BasicTabbedPaneUI::calculateTabRect` which is a big ugly method.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution.

As @Joe Coder said, you have to override the `calculateTabRects()` method. However, this method is in an inner class. There is no way to extend the `BasicTabbedPaneUI`, or the inner class, because there are just too many protected and private fields. The solution is to recreate the relevant classes by copy-pasting all their code.

The source code is from [here](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/tree/master/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic).

The relevant modification is in the `calculateTabRects()` method, more specifically in that for loop:

```
// Step through runs from back to front to calculate
// tab y locations and to pad runs appropriately
for (i = runCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //...
}
```

Simply iterating in reverse does the trick: `for (i = 0; i < runCount; i++) {...}`

Now, if you copy-paste the code of the `BasicTabbedPaneUI`, you'll find that you need to also copy-paste `LazyActionMap` and `BasicGraphicsUtils`.

For convenience, here is all the code you need to copy-paste. Make sure not to override the package, if it's not in the package `javax.swing.plaf.basic` it won't work.

FixedTabbedPaneUI.java: https://pastebin.com/W8RBD4vg

LazyActionMap2.java: https://pastebin.com/RKtDgJB5

BasicGraphicsUtils2.java: https://pastebin.com/Au4hcSyp

But, in my case, I need a `WindowsTabbedPaneUI`. So here's WindowsTabbedPaneUI2.java: https://pastebin.com/89UedgbQ

..XPStyle2.java: https://pastebin.com/xCsm8DZc

..and AnimationController2.java: https://pastebin.com/7Pm0s5eG

The OOP hell finishes here, but in the current state, the lines between "runs" (tab lines) disappear:
[image]

The solution is to put the following after choosing the UI with `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`:

```
    UIManager.getDefaults().put("TabbedPane.tabRunOverlay", 0);
    UIManager.getDefaults().put("TabbedPane.focus", new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve it easier by extending `BasicTabbedPaneUI` and overriding `createLayoutManager`, and in there return `TabbedPaneLayout` that override a necessary method.